# Kendo grid MVVM

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I have kendo grid with column re-sizable option. When I double click on column header that column should re-size to auto width (ref:"jsfiddle.net/YF7ny/").

I need this options through MVVM (Model-View-View Model). I am new to this kendo & mvvm concepts, please help me.

Comment: What does "I need this options through MVVM (Model-View-View Model)" mean? I do not understand what does MVVM have to do with a column resize.

Comment: Hi onabai, please refer this "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/index". this framework will be used to implement for column resize

Answer (score 0):

To add your double-click handler you would need to make a custom MVVM binder.
There is some documentation on making a custom binder here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom

Then your grid element could have something like

```
data-bind="gridColumnResize: x"
```

---

Another alternative is to extend the default Grid widget and make your own, and in the `init` you can add your double-click handler.

---

Since this is JavaScript, you could even overwrite the existing Kendo Grid widget and add this feature to all grids.